# Writing Windows Service in C# .NET Core for Windows & Azure Cloud

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

**Background:** We have developed a Windows Service in C# .NET 4.5. The service does two jobs at once.

1. It communicates with LDAP and reads the user statuses and updates in the Database.
2. It communicates with the Database and rolls out items to users.

**Requirement:** We have got the opportunity to rewrite the service in .NET Core. We need to write the service to achieve the following targets.

1. The old clients who are using their own infrastructure could install and use the service like they are doing now.
2. The clients who are using CLOUD should be able to install it on the cloud. But I don't think for a single service we are required to use VM. Is there a better way to handle this scenario?
3. The service's 1st part is communicating with LDAP. Clients who are using the cloud, definitely have the database hosted on the cloud along with the other Web Applications but where should be the service installed so it can easily communicate with the LDAP as well as with the database (2nd part)?

I heard about the background worker process. Does the windows service be used as a background worker process and as a windows service at the same time?

Comment: Isn't `BackgroundWorker` a Windows Forms component to help take the load of the UI thread? Not sure why it would be of any use in a Windows Service or are you talking about something different?

Comment: "We have got the opportunity to rewrite the service in .NET Core." - hardly a big task.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core take a look at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService for windows services.

As far as the Cloud issue I assume it would depend on how the customer is setup.  If LDAP is still on-prem, I assume it would be easier to have the service running on-prem as they would probably have a connection to the VPC on the Cloud where the database is hosted.

If everything exists on the Cloud then I assume it would the depend on the provider how you can run the service?  Small EC2 instance on Amazon, on Azure you might have to use a VM or maybe look at a WebJob on an AppService, not very familiar with Google.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Fernando for your reply. Actually, I want to use the same code targeting both scenarios. One is on-premises as the windows service. Second WebJob as you mentioned above. I know using VM I can achieve this but what I have to do to run the same windows service code using WebJob?

Comment: Not sure how to detect the envrionment at installation time but one posiblity is to distribute just the executable withouth the service installation options for WebJob clients and add the Windows Service options for those that will isntall it as a windows service.  The actuall execution should be rather simiar for both.